# String.Split for new lines working with string[] but not with char[]

Tags: c#

check this code:

```
   string t = @"\nazerty \n\nazerty \n\nazerty \nazerty";

   string[] firstMethod = t.Split(new char[]{'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   string[] secondMethod = t.Split(new string[]{@"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

why does first method NOT work and second does ???

Thx

Comment: You are using a verbatim string so you don't actually have any `\n` characters - what you have is "\\n".

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any newlines. It contains backslashes. Your second Split call is splitting on "backslash followed by n". Your first Split call is splitting on genuine newlines. It's not at all clear what you mean by "work" and "not work"... we don't know what you expected to happen, or what actually happened.

Comment: @JonSkeet based on the fact that OP is trying to split on the newline character, my guess would be that this is an erroneous (unintentional?) use of verbatim strings.

Comment: @AntP: Yes, I suspect so too. The fact that the title says that the split with strings works, but the body says that it doesn't is contradictory too.

Comment: Figure it out yourself http://pastebin.com/QWvAze6p that's the difference between the two calls.

Comment: Sorry guys, I mean first method does not work and second method does split as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you are using verbatim strings, i.e.:

```
string t = @"\nazerty \n\nazerty \n\nazerty \nazerty";
```

... is equivalent to:

```
string t = "\\nazerty \\n\\nazerty \\n\\nazerty \\nazerty";
```

It's likely that you actually wanted the following, which uses newline characters instead of literal backslash-n:

```
string t = "\nazerty \n\nazerty \n\nazerty \nazerty";
```

This would be "successfully" split on either `new[] { "\n" }` or `new[] { '\n' }` (but *not* `new[] { @"\n" }` which expects backslash-backslash-n).